# C++ 11 Regexpression

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-c++

How can I use C++ 11 RegEx to find "time" in the following pattern:

```
"time = '1212232' or raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd'"
```

and convert it to:

```
 "timeStamp = '1212232' or raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd'".
```

It should not affect the other occurrence of other "time" word.

Comment: `std::regex_replace(data, std::regex("\\*\\*time\\*\\*"), "**timestamp**");`

Comment: sorry it now i modified my string it is not \*\*time\*\* it is just time

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Is the `time` that you want to replace always at the beginning of the line??

Comment: @Praveen: Not only begginging suppose my string can be "raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd' or time = '1212232'  " . In this case my result shoud be "raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd' or timeStamp = '1212232'  " . It may be in any position.

Comment: Why regex? Why less maintainable and hard to read code?

Answer (score 3):

Try a combination of `std::string::find` and `std::string::replace`.

This gets the position:

`size_t f = s.find("time");`

And this replaces the text:

`s.replace(f, std::string("time").length(), "timeStamp");`

**Source code:** http://cpp.sh/3ljv

```
int main()
{
  std::string name = "time = '1212232' or raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd'";
  size_t f = name.find("time");
  std::cout << name.replace(f, std::string("time").length(), "timeStamp");
}
```

**Output:**

> timeStamp = '1212232' or raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd

If you want to replace all occurrences, you could use a function like this:

```
bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}

replace(str, "time", "timeStamp");
```

Comment: I need to specificaly replace time, suppose i have string "raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd' or time = '1212232'" in this case your example replaces to  "raisetimeStamp ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd' or time = '1212232'". which is incorrect   becasuse it replaces only first occurance.

Comment: no... it will search for `**time**` and replace it not every `time`

Comment: @ACS: You're wrong, mine will replace instances of `**time**` to `**timeStamp**`, which is exactly what you asked for. It would ignore instances of `time` and/or `raisetime`, etc.

Comment: sorry it now i modified my string it is not \*\*time\*\* it is just time

Comment: it shoud replace only time but not first occurance, if my string changed to  "raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd' or time = '1212232' " then from your example it replaces raiseTime to raiseTimeStamp, but i need answer like  "raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd' or timeStamp = '1212232' "

Comment: You can't keep asking for multiple answers to a question. I answered your original one. You should really be asking a separate question if that's the case.

Comment: If you're only interested in `time =` then simply use that as the matched string instead of `time`.

Answer (score 2):

If using regex is required, then probably the most simplest solution is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::regex_replace(
    "raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd' or time = '1212232'",
    std::regex(R"((\btime)( = '\d+'))"),
    "$1Stamp$2") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It will replace any string like "time = '123'" to "timeStamp = '123'"

Output:

> raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd' or timeStamp = '1212232'

Comment: I guess this would work and if you wanted to replace all occurrences you could just use `regex("time")` instead of `regex("^time")`.

Comment: @gotnull correct replace all occurrences will require more code and more complex regexp, especially if we would like to remain text in '' unchanged. Matching pattern may be similar to: "(time) = \d"

Comment: @gotnull changed the answer to replace the occurrence in any place of the string

Answer (score 1):

If we consider your example input...

> "time = '1212232' or raisetime ='1212' or AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time cd'"

...two things are pretty obvious:

- if it weren't for the single-quoted strings, just looking for a word boundary, "time", some optional whitespace, then "=", would work pretty well: regexp `\btime\s*=`
- the single-quoted strings significantly complicate things, needing fairly advanced regexp rules, as the above might match the quoted content (it doesn't with your example due to the check for `=`, but would match `AlarmParameter1 = 'abc time = cd'`)

That suggests a simple solution:

- make a copy of the input string
- iterate over that copy, replacing anything inside single quotes with say whitespace
- apply the regexp search `\b(time)\s*=` to find the "time" submatch of interest
- iterate over the copy again, restoring anything inside single quotes from the original string
- replace the submatch with the replacement text (use the string indices reported for the submatch)

It'll need more lines of code than a regexp-only solution, but will be easier to get right and maintain.

Answer (score -1):

To do this reliably, you cannot use regular expressions.

You need to *parse* the code snippet into an AST, change all occurrences of the *identifier* `time` and then convert the AST back into text.